# PHP method operations affecting variables in another method

Tags: php, oop

In the code below the method formatDates() doesn't return anything, yet when I do a var_dump in getMeetData() the dates are formatted. Why is this? I always thought that due to variable scope operations that happened to a variable within one method stayed within that method & wouldn't affect the variables in any methods outside of it.

I've clearly misunderstood something & haven't found anything helpful in my searches, although I suspect part of the reason is I don't really know how to phrase the search term.

```
public function getMeetData($limit = NULL){
    $meet_data = $this->retrieve_meets->retrieveBasicMeetData($limit);
    $this->formatDates($meet_data);

    var_dump($meet_data);
}

protected function formatDates($meet_data){
    foreach($meet_data as $key => $value){
        $meet_data[$key]->start_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value->start_date));
        $meet_data[$key]->end_date = date("d/m/Y", strtotime($value->end_date));
    }
}
```

I've put the results of a var_dump from getMeetData(), without a call to formatDates (I commented $this->formatDates($meet_data); out) below:

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[76]
      public 'title' => string 'Meeting' (length=22)
      public 'slug' => string 'meeting-november-2015' (length=36)
      public 'start_date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
      public 'end_date' => string '2015-10-30' (length=10)
      public 'activities' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Meeting' (length=7)
```

Below is the results from the same data used above but with a call to formatDates()

```
array (size=5)
  0 => 
    object(stdClass)[76]
      public 'title' => string 'Meeting' (length=22)
      public 'slug' => string 'meeting-november-2015' (length=36)
      public 'start_date' => string '30/10/2015' (length=10)
      public 'end_date' => string '30/10/2015' (length=10)
      public 'activities' => 
        array (size=1)
          0 => string 'Meeting' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$meet_data is an object and "objects are passed by references by default" in PHP. See http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.references.php

Comment: I see, I had just assumed they were passed around like variables. Although passing them by reference does make more sense now you've pointed it out.

Comment: funny, the next line after what you posted is `This is not completely true.`.

Comment: @Sean Could you elaborate a little? Even if it's just a few notes on what to look up.

Comment: @Sean, you are right, but that doesn't mean you have still a different thing. "When an object is sent by argument, returned or assigned to another variable, the different variables are not aliases: they hold a copy of the identifier, which points to the same object." Here, "This is not completely true" actually means that it is not a reference, it's just the same object.

Comment: @NeilNand, you will understand it, if you follow that link and also what Sean is talking about.

Comment: @NeilNand my comment was just that the statement that @ TareqMahmood copied/pasted from the link was followed by `This is not completely true`. My suggestion is for you to read the php docs, specifically the link in this answer. Context is key.